# Upload a file with SSH and then give back the control to the user

Tags: shell, ssh, zsh

I'm trying to create a script that, when you connect on a remote server with SSH, the script checks things and deploy your personals scripts before giving you back the stdin, all in one SSH connection (else you have to authenticate multiple times...).

I have a script that works.

```
#!/bin/zsh
HOST="$1"

# Install ZSH if it's not already installed
ssh "$HOST" <<- EOF
    if [ ! -x /bin/zsh ]; then
        if [ -x "/usr/bin/dnf" ]; then
            sudo dnf install -y zsh >/dev/null
        elif [ -x "/usr/bin/apt-get" ]; then
            sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y zsh >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
EOF

# Copy ZSH configuration to remote host
tar -cz -f - -C "$HOME" --exclude="*.zwc" {.zshrc,.zshenv,.config/zsh/{p10k.zsh,plugins}} | ssh "$HOST" 'tar -xz -f - -C "$HOME"'

# Login with ZSH in a login shell
ssh -t "$HOST" 'SHELL=/bin/zsh /bin/zsh -l'
```

But it uses multiple connections for that. How can I just use one connection ?

I tried a POC

```
#!/bin/zsh
HOST="$1"

# redirect 3 to standard output
exec 3>&1

ssh -t $HOST >&3 <&1 &

# doesn't work, doesnt execute on remote host
echo "hostname"
# this as well
echo "hostname" >&1

# works, give back the tty of the remote server to the user
exec 1<&0

wait
echo "THE END"
```

But I cannot execute commands on the remote server before giving back the tty. And I don't know how to send file either.

Is there a way to do all of that ?

Comment: If the goal is just to avoid authenticating multiple times, then fix your ssh-agent to cache credentials

Comment: I'm using MFA with FIDO2 hardware key that check user presence, that's not a problem of ssh-agent. And in an enterprise context your connections are logged, logging 3 connections each time you SSH, it's not for the best ...

Comment: I haven't done SSH with MFA with FIDO2 in a corporate environment, but my recollection is that you typically get an authentication token that SSH then uses, and is free to reuse, for a finite amount of time, a bit like a Kerberos ticket ("Active Directory" in the Windows world). That would perfectly describe your situation here: ssh-agent acquires the token and holds on to it for as long as it's valid.

Comment: Yes I see, this what I was doing before, but now, they require to enter a PIN, and touch the hardware key each time you initiate a connection. Which is a burden if you have to do it 3 times :-)

Comment: yes, but as far as I know (and I might really be wrong here), authenticating using secret key + PIN + touch yields you an auth token that isn't linked to a single SSH session, but valid for some time. That's what I mean – you should be OK with just doing this once, for multiple short sessions.

Comment: It does not create an auth token, and it would defeat that kind of protection, as fido2 requires each time to authenticate with a PIN. If the subject interest you: https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/Securing_SSH_with_FIDO2.html

I think you are talking of the ControlMaster mechanism of SSH. But i do not want to use that mechanism as it weakens the security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending that shell code, the tar file and then user's input all with one `ssh -t` via the same stream, while at the same time letting `ssh` possibly ask for password or key passphrases would be extremely clumsy and brittle.

If your conf files are not too big and can fit in an environment variable and the remote sshd has a `AcceptEnv LC_*` in its configuration (as is common), you could pass the tgz file base64 encoded in one of those:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
HOST=${1?}

LC_ZC=$(
  tar -cz -f - -C ~ --exclude="*.zwc" {.zshrc,.zshenv,.config/zsh/{p10k.zsh,plugins}} |
    base64
) exec ssh -o SendEnv=LC_ZC -t "$HOST" '
  if ! command -v zsh; then
    if command -v dnf; then
      sudo dnf install -y zsh
    elif command -v apt-get; then
      sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y zsh
    fi
  fi > /dev/null

  echo "$LC_ZC" | base64 -d | tar -zxf - -C ~
  unset -v LC_ZC
  SHELL=/bin/zsh exec /bin/zsh -l'
```

(also assumes the login shell of the user on the remote machine is POSIX-like).

If not, easiest is probably to use several `ssh` invocations but all sharing the same login session with the connection multiplexing feature (see description of `ControlMaster`/`ControlPath`/`ControlPersist` in the man page and/or look on this site for examples).

Another approach, with recent versions of openssh would be to use `-R remote_socket:local_socket` and use a Unix-domain socket to transfer the tar files (using zsh's `zsh/net/socket` module for instance).

Comment: That solution is interesting! I would not thought of passing my whole config in a VAR.
I already thought of ControlMaster, but I'm kind of reluctant to use that mechanism, as it opens a channel without security checks, which kind of defeat the purpose of using fido2 keys to secure the connection in the first place, I will consider it tho ...

Comment: @Shengis access to the control socket is going to be restricted. If you can't trust the admins on the  machines, there's not much you can do, they'd be able to hook themselves in the ssh process to do whatever they want with or without that control socket or replace the ssh command, etc. You can also terminate that control socket as soon as it's no longer needed.

Comment: Well, it's another subject, but I was more thinking of a protection against rogue processes of the same user, which is why you need to authenticate with a hardware token (to check the user presence). There is some effort on Linux to try to diminish what a malware (which is not root) can do to the same user, like the wayland effort, it's far from perfect, but it's good to think about it nonetheless.